# PopupWindow padding - too large

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `PopupWindow` that I am using in my `Activity`, and everything works fine except for the padding of the elements contained within the `PopupWindow` - it's much too large - literally taking up most of the small PopupWindows space. Here is the XML I use to define the `PopupWindow`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/homescreen_popup_bg_levels">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FF000000"
    android:textSize="12dp">
</TextView>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/y"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#FF000000">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of the `PopupWindow`:

[image]

Any idea why the text is being padded down and to the right so much? I've tried adjusting the XML padding, etc but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The issue was indeed the padding of the 9-patch image - not including any meant the OS was guessing as to where to allow text, and pushing that text towards the center. Setting the padding element of the 9-patch images used for the background solved the issue.

Oh, and something else to note... when using a level list, it appears that Android is only looking at the padding of the first image that is loaded, then applying that to each and every image. As I am (was) using the levels to contain four asymmetric images (call-outs to the top left, right, bottom left, right), all of the images are getting the same padding, pixel for pixel, as the first one that gets loaded.

To solve this issue, I'm now simply setting the background image dynamically, rather than changing the level.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your issue is the homescreen_popup_bg_levels drawable.

Try removing it and see what happens. If that's the issue, create a correct 9-patch.

Comment: Hmm, well the image you are seeing above is a 9-patch with no padding, just a single dot in the middle left, middle top to stretch. There are four 'levels for the drawing (orientations of top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right, and all of the images are the same in terms of being a 9-patch and having no padding box... maybe I need to define one?